# How to update an array of exponential moving average in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I'm using `pandas.ewma` to compute the exponential moving average of a time series. As new data are appended to the time series, I also need to update its exponential moving average array. How can I do this, without recomputing exponential moving average from the beginning of the time series.

Here's my example code

```
ema = pd.ewma(ts, span = 10)
ts = np.append(ts, [25], 0)
# I would not like to do this to update ema since all of the ema except the last one have already been computed:
ema = pd.ewma(ts, span = 10)
```

Comment: @Merlin What I've tried in shown in the code provided. The specific data are not essential to the problem, so I did not include it.

Comment: The data is essential to asking a question on SO. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1):

Algebraically, it is clear that this can be done.

The EWMA for time *m* [can be shown to be](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moving_average#Exponential_moving_average)

*∑ <sub>i = 1</sub><sup>m</sup>[α<sup>m - i</sup> y<sub>i</sub>]*.

Suppose you have this for all values up to *m* (which you do). For any *n ≥ m*, the EWMA is

*∑ <sub>i = 1</sub><sup>n</sup>[α<sup>n - i</sup> y<sub>i</sub>] = ∑ <sub>i = 1</sub><sup>m</sup>[α<sup>n - i</sup> y<sub>i</sub>] + ∑ <sub>i = m + 1</sub><sup>n</sup>[α<sup>n - i</sup> y<sub>i</sub>]*.

For the first term on the right hand side, we have

*∑ <sub>i = 1</sub><sup>m</sup>[α<sup>n - i</sup> y<sub>i</sub>] = α<sup>n - m</sup> ∑ <sub>i = 1</sub><sup>m</sup>[α<sup>m - i</sup> y<sub>i</sub>]*,

which is exactly *α<sup>n - m</sup>* times the last element of the EWMA on the first *m* elements. Let us call it *Y<sub>m</sub>*.

For the second term on the right hand side, we have

*∑ <sub>i = m + 1</sub><sup>n</sup>[α<sup>n - i</sup> y<sub>i</sub>] = 
∑ <sub>i - m = 1</sub><sup>n - m</sup>[α<sup>n - m - (i - m)</sup> y<sub>i - m + m</sub>] = 
∑ <sub>j = 1</sub><sup>n - m</sup>[α<sup>n - m - j</sup> y<sub>j + m</sub>]*.

Combining both simplifications, we have

*∑ <sub>i = 1</sub><sup>n</sup>[α<sup>n - i</sup> y<sub>i</sub>] = 
∑ <sub>j = 1</sub><sup>n - m</sup>[α<sup>n - m - j</sup> y<sub>j + m</sub>] + α<sup>n - m + 1</sup>(Y<sub>m</sub> / α<sup>n - m + 1</sup>)*.

This is exactly the calculation of an *n - m + 1* EWMA, with starting element *Y<sub>m</sub> / α<sup>n - m + 1</sup>*. Thus, it is unnecessary to calculate everything from the start.

I leave it to anyone else interested, the final technical task of adapting this to [`pd.ewma`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.ewma.html), which, e.g., defines *α* indirectly through `halflife`. (Surely the downvoter of the answer has already solved this end to end, for example.)

Comment: In pandas 18.0 pd.ewma is replaced by [series.ewm](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.ewm.html) where you can specify alpha directly.

Comment: @ayhan Thanks! Great to know that.